# Where can I park and get public transportation to SoFi stadium in Los Angeles?

Tags: public-transport, automobiles, los-angeles

Some friends and I are going to the Chargers game at [SoFi Stadium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoFi_Stadium) .

The parking is sold out and I've been trying to figure out a way to park somewhere nearby and ride public transportation to the stadium.

We're coming from the North, down the 405 freeway from north of Santa Clarita. There is a train line from Hollywood but that seems to take you to downtown LA where you then have to walk and get a bus back north to the stadium.

I've seen some parking at some Green Line stations that have a bus to the stadium but the only seem to have a limited number of parking spots that would fill up quick.

I've searched the metro sites but am not sure what to do. I don't want to spend half the day trying to find an open space.

Any suggestions as to how to get to the stadium?

Comment: Are you only interested in public transportation routes, or just getting to the stadium?  There are offsite lots with shuttles to the stadium that are not sold out.

Comment: [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com) returns several combinations of train, tram, and bus.

Comment: @BowlOfRed - just getting to the stadium any way possible that doesn't take too long.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at the Inglewood parking shuttles.  You pay both for parking and for each individual taking a shuttle.  But there appears to be capacity available even for events that have a very short lead time.
https://inglewoodparkgo.com/

A less expensive option seems to be the [Gardena 7x Bus line](https://ridegtrans.com/line/7x/).  It runs for games and picks up from the Harbor Gateway transit Center ($3 parking on game days).   I couldn't find anything recent, but a 2018 [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Chargers/comments/a4gd09/does_the_harbor_gateway_transit_center_parking/) said that the facility did not fill up on game days.